# Using (redefined) macro in \caption doesn't work, but it works in another environment

Tags: macros, captions

My problem is strange behavior my command `\vec{}` in `\caption`. I used this construction:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\accentset{\rightarrow}{#1}}
```

See my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, czech, twoside]{book} 
 \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsbsy}  
 \usepackage{accents}        
 \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,unicode-math} 
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Calibri}
    \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Candara}
    \setmonofont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Consolas}        
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\accentset{\rightarrow}{#1}}

    \begin{figure}[hb!]
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
              \coordinate (dS) at (2,0.5);
              \draw[->] (dS) ++ (0.25,0.25) -- +(1,0.5) node[right]{$\vec{n}$};
              \draw[->] (dS) ++ (0.25,0.25) -- +(2,1.5) node[right]{$\vec{h}$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{FYZ:fig_01}
        \caption{vector $\vec{n}$.}   
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

SW: MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit up to date. When I try to use the command `\vec` in a `tikzpicture` environment, everything all right, but with caption an error occurs. I don't understand it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\accentset` makes your command fragile so you need `\protect\vec{n}` or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: It seems, then, that I did not choose a suitable method. Which way should you gave yourself. I drew from the library physymb at page 10, where is: `\ifthenelse{\boolean{pboldvectors}}%
 {\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}}%
{\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}}`

Comment: needing `\protect` did not mean you did anything wrong (many standard latex commands need `\protect`) however as the memory available now is so much more than available in 1990's it makes sense to use a bit extra memory and make your definition robust. Using `\DeclareRobustCommand` is the easiest to use as teh syntax is like `\newcommand`. An alternative would be to use the e-tex mechanism `\protected\def\vec#1{\accentset{\rightarrow}{#1}`  e-tex protection is technically different from the LaTeX `\protect` mechanism (which pre-dated e-tex) but in cases like this you can use either

Comment: Firt method (using protect) works me, but e-tex mechanism no. I tried a simple replacement \renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\accentset{\rightarrow}{#1}} by \protected\def\vec#1{\accentset{\rightarrow}{#1}. I would also like to additionally thank you for your advice.

Comment: oh I thought that would have worked, I may test it later and add another comment

Comment: @jafan,david `\protected \def\vec#1{\accentset{\rightarrow}{#1}` is missing a final closing brace: is this the error we're talking about, or is it something else?

Comment: any of my input should be checked for typing errors (@wasteofspace has known me too long:-)